# Really weird segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

In the following code I call the `editorOpen` method with a file name.
It always makes a segmentation fault except for when I comment out the first line in `editorUpdateRow` (`std::string rowStr(row);`).
Can someone explain why that happens?

```
void editorUpdateRow(const std::string& row)
{
    std::string rowStr(row);
    size_t index = 0;
    while (index != std::string::npos)
    {
        index = rowStr.find("\t", index);
        if (index != std::string::npos)
        {    
            rowStr.replace(index, 1, KILO_TAB);
            index += sizeof(KILO_TAB) - 1;
        }
    }
}

void editorAppendRow(char* row, size_t len)
{
    config.rows = static_cast<std::string*>(realloc(config.rows, sizeof(std::string) * (config.numRows + 1)));
    KILO_SANITY(config.rows != nullptr, "Couldn't realloc rows array");
    printf("%d\n", config.numRows);
    config.rows[config.numRows] = row;
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    config.rows[config.numRows][len] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
    editorUpdateRow(config.rows[config.numRows]);

    ++config.numRows;
}

void editorOpen(char* filename)
{
    KILO_SANITY(filename != nullptr, "Filename is NULL!!!");
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    KILO_SANITY(fp, "Open of %s Failed!!!", filename);
    char* line = nullptr;
    size_t linecap = 0;
    ssize_t linelen = 0;
    while((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, fp)) != -1)
    {
            while (linelen > 0 && (line[linelen - 1] == '\n' ||
                   line[linelen - 1] == '\r'))
            {
                --linelen;
            }
            editorAppendRow(line, linelen);
    }

    free(line);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` don't work with `std::string`s. Use `new` instead.

Comment: Better still, don't explicitly dynamically allocate strings - there is almost never any need to.

Comment: Put away the `C` coding and use`std::vector<std::string>`.  All of those calls to `free` and `realloc` will not work.  A `std::string` must be properly constructed, and those functions know nothing about C++ and object construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::string` is a non-trivial class that requires proper construction to function. `malloc` simply allocates memory. It does not run the constructor, so the allocated `string`'s state is uninitialized. The `string`'s internal character buffer points Crom knows where, its length is undefined, and whatever other bookkeeping is used in the string's implementation is not set to meaningful values. A `malloc`ed `string` is a bomb waiting to go off.

Because `malloc` is dangerous to use with complex data types (and because it's possible to get the size wrong), it should almost never be used in C++.

When forced to allocate dynamic storage, prefer (in order)

1. [a library container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)
2. [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)
3. [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)
4. `new`

Pick the earliest one in the list that fits your object's requirements.

By itself, `string` almost is a library container, a container of characters, so dynamically allocating a `string` is almost never the correct option. You can pass it around by reference and transfer ownership [with `std::move`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) if you wish to avoid copying.